# PTIJ: Live Feed and Halacha

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Is watching a live feed contrary to halacha because of the injunction of אבר מן החי? Would the biggest concern be one of More eat ayin?

Alternately, if one does not eat via the eyes, could a live stream be used as mikvah?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: @Daniel אבר מן ה**חי**? "Live" animal? "Live" stream? Oh, forget it. Jokes are like frogs - they're not funny once dissected, and since frogs are treif, they're also אסור בהנאה.

Answer (score 3):

The Talmud (Chulin 49a) establishes that one can eat with the eyes.

> א"ר יוחנן למה נקרא שמה ריאה שמאירה את העינים איבעיא להו לאכילה
>
> Rabbi Yochanan said: Why is it called seeing that which enlightens the eyes? They needed to know: Becuase of eating.

Rashi explains that they eat as the eyes are used.

> לאכילה - האוכלין אותה כמו שהיא
>
> Because of eating - Those who eat just as it is.

The Kaf HaChiam in Yoreh Deah (36:110) learns that a buggy live stream is forbidden to view on account of *ever min hachai*.

> תולעים הנמצאים בריאה אסורים דבר תורה משום אבר מן החי
>
> Bugs found in the viewing are forbidden from the Torah becuase of *ever min hachai*.

The Rama (OC 225) states that one should ideally recite the blessing after the live stream has been completed.

> ומי שבירך בשעת ראייה לא הפסיד (טור) ואין לברך עד שנגמר תשלום גידול הפירי (תשובת רשב"א סי' ר"נ וכל בו) ואם לא בירך בראייה ראשונה יכול לברך בראייה שניה (אגור)
>
> One who blesses during the viewing has not lost out, but it is ideal to wait for the entire matter to be completed. However, if after the first time viewing one has not yet made a blessing, the blessing may still be made by the second viewing.

Answer (score 1):

When one is immersed in the live stream, it would depend on what is being seen as well as if it is considered coming from an artificial source. For example, the live streaming of the siyum hashas should be considered as creating *taharah* as it is created from the *Wellsprings of Torah*.

Answer (score 0):

No, but according to Rambam ([Hilchot Rotzeach Ushemirat Nefesh 9:2, Chabad.org translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088925/jewish/Rotzeach-uShmirat-Nefesh-Chapter-Nine.htm)) you can decapitate a calf there:

> After they measure and establish which city is closest, they bury the person who was murdered in the place he was found. The elders from Jerusalem return to their city, and the court of the city that was designated brings a calf paid for by all the inhabitants. They bring the the calf to a river that flows forcefully. This is the meaning of the term eitan found in the Torah (Deuteronomy 21:4).